# Mongodb aggregation lookup from the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following documents which show specific data of a selected Stock for the selected day.
MOSC, SHL, DDSM values are the signals. So if either of them are greater than 0 this indicates positive signal for that stock.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a02b76de39412a1ce52d0c"),
    "Date" : ISODate("2022-12-13T00:00:00.000+0000"),
    "Stock" : "ALFAS",
    "Open" : 286.0,
    "High" : 308.3,
    "Low" : 285.0,
    "Price" : 308.3,
    "Change" : 9.99,
    "MOSC" : NumberInt(0),
    "SHL" : NumberInt(0),
    "DDSM" : NumberInt(0),
    "TF" : "D"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a02b76de39412a1ce52cf5"),
    "Date" : ISODate("2022-12-13T00:00:00.000+0000"),
    "Stock" : "ACSEL",
    "Open" : 82.2,
    "High" : 84.0,
    "Low" : 81.0,
    "Price" : 82.15,
    "Change" : 0.18,
    "MOSC" : NumberInt(67),
    "SHL" : NumberInt(0),
    "DDSM" : NumberInt(0),
    "TF" : "D"
}
```

```
{ $or : [ { "MOSC" : { $gt : 0.0 } }, { "SHL" : { $gt : 0.0 } }, { "DDSM" : { $gt : 0.0 } } ], "Date" : ISODate("2022-12-12T00:00:00.000+0000") }
```

So this query returns positive stocks for the selected day.
However i need to add new fields showing the changes and the sum of changes for the next days like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a02b76de39412a1ce52cf5"),
    "Date" : ISODate("2022-12-13T00:00:00.000+0000"),
    "Stock" : "ACSEL",
    "Open" : 82.2,
    "High" : 84.0,
    "Low" : 81.0,
    "Price" : 82.15,
    "Change" : 0.18,
    "MOSC" : NumberInt(67),
    "SHL" : NumberInt(0),
    "DDSM" : NumberInt(0),
    "TF" : "D",
    "Change 1D" : 3.83,
    "Change 2D" : -2.93,
    "Change 3D" : -1.09,
    "SUM 3D" :   -0.19
}
```

I'm new to mongodb so this is important for me to get an idea on how to build up aggregations that i need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear, however [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) may help you